# trouble installing Zend framework on wamp server

Tags: zend-framework, installation

I am having severe trouble installing Zend framework to my system and would really appreciate any advise given. i have followed all the recommended advise so far but still seem to get the following message from my windows powershell command when I type in zf:

*ZF Error  ****

**In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework is inside your  include_path.**

I followed the following steps:

1. I installed Zend Libraries and bin in the following folders in my laptop ( windows 7):
   **C:\wamp\bin\php**
   this is the same  bin folder that holds my PHP 5.43. The Zend is held in a folder called:
   **zendframwork**;
2. I then went to my php.ini folder ( includes path- ) and inserted the following:
   **include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\zendframwork"**
3. I then went to change my **advanced windows settings**: once there, I clicked onto Environment Variables, then to System variable where I double clicked on to **paths line**.

   in the **paths line** I included the path to the bin folder for the zend bin i.e.:

   **zend_tool_include_path= C:\wamp\bin\php\zendframwork\library**
4. I then rebooted my systems and then went into windows powershell to test the installation. but it still seems unable to locate the library

Can somebody please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: In your `php.ini` shouldn't you have `include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\zendframwork\library`?

Comment: hi Rolando . i tried it with the 'library' at the end and also without the 'library' at the end. it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the following, the Zend directory is typically in the library folder under zend framework.

> I then went to my php.ini folder ( includes path- ) and inserted the
>   following: include_path = **".;C:\wamp\bin\php\zendframwork\library"**
>
> I then went to change my advanced windows settings: once there, i
>   clicked onto Environment Variables, then to System variable where i
>   double clicked on to paths line.

in your environment variables you need to *edit* the variable named *Path* and append the path to the zf.bat file, typically found in your zend framework directory named *bin*, so you'll end up with a *Path* variable something like:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\www\Zend Framework\bin;
```

I've never seen this variable (zend_tool_include_path) in any installation, so I don't know if you need it or not.

> in the paths line i included the path to the bin folder for the zend
>   bin ie:
>   **zend_tool_include_path**= C:\wamp\bin\php\zendframwork\library

I'm not sure powershell is the answer, I use the CLI (type cmd at the run box) and just type `zf show version` at the command prompt to test if Zend_Tool is working.

> I then rebooted my systems and then went into windows powershell to
>   test the installation. but it still seems unable to locate the library

Comment: hi everyone. i have now resolved this matter. thank you for all your help